# emacs bind key to the insertion of another

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have `paredit-forward` and `paredit-backward` bound to > and < respectively.

This means if I want to type "something->something-else" I instead type "something-" the cursor is teleported to another part of the screen, and finish typing with "something-else".

My solution to this is to use `C-.` and `C-,` to insert them.
I tried this:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-.") (kbd ">"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-,") (kbd "<"))
```

The previous command results in the **another paredit-forward keybind** because I am creating a keybind chain like so:

```
C-. → > → paredit-forward
```

Instead of

```
C-. → > → the "greater than" key is inserted into whatever text box I am in.
```

which is what I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys are bound to *commands*. Commands are usually interactive functions, but can also be keyboard macros (in either string or vector format). Executing a keyboard macro causes Emacs to do the things which the macro's key sequences would cause to be done.

`(kbd ">")` results in the keyboard macro `">"`; so you have told Emacs that when `C-.` is typed, it should do the things which are done when `>` is typed.

*Normally* (in most buffers) `>` would be bound to `self-insert-command`, and therefore the keyboard macro `(kbd ">")` *would* simply insert a `>` character, but you've modified that binding.

I believe you want to bind `C-.` to a command which inserts a `>` character. Such a command is:

```
(lambda () (interactive) (insert ">"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a different scheme, but a 'self-insert-command is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** need to bind a special key (e.g., `C-,`) to a special command (e.g., `(lambda () (interactive) (insert ">"))`) that inserts a given character (e.g., `>`).

Emacs already provides a *general* key, bound to a *general* command, that inserts **any** character: the key **`C-q`**.

All you ever need to do, to insert any character that corresponds to a keyboard key (and other characters as well), is to **hit `C-q` and then hit that key**.

So the answer for you is to just do this:

- **`C-q >`** to insert `>`
- **`C-q <`** to insert `<`