# Emacs: I want to put # on my mac when I press §

Tags: emacs

All of my other editors and terminals have it set so that pressing the para § gives me a # instead. I never use para but do use # all the time.

I know this should be utterly trivial, but all of the global-set-key examples I can find are for mapping functions or doing things like auto inserting closing parens.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834684/emacs-bind-key-to-the-insertion-of-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in your `.emacs` / init file:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "§") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))
```